# In Mathematics is there a discrete logarithm function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, special-functions, math-history, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

[image]

I find it difficult to understand this part [in this book.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/discrete.logs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwig_uSll4PgAhUJqaQKHfevD54QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3X8iKrzGY__hQ7YV-b_e5x)

Because, as far as I know, there is no unique function or formula for discrete logarithms. I cann't understand what this formula does. Is this formula to direct calculate the discrete logarithm?
Or is there a direct unique formula or funtion that calculates special discrete logarithms?

Comment: You need to unknow what you know, because it is wrong. There very mush **is** a function, and behold, even a formula.

Comment: @IvanNeretin unique formula?

Comment: There is no such thing as unique formula.

Comment: Once you have fixed a generator $g$, every non-zero element is of the form $g^k$ for some integer $k$. If you restrict $1\leq k \leq p-1$, there there is exactly only one $k$. So the function must be unique: if $h = g^r$ then the discrete log function $f$ must give you exactly $f(h) = r$. However since we can define multiple formulas for $f$, there is no unique formula. In particular the one you listed, by Wells, is one such formula (I guess your question would extend to proving this formula).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the discrete logarithm used there: if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$ - that is, it generates the multiplicative group mod $p$ - and $u\not\equiv 0\mod p$ then $\log_g u$ is $\min\{L: g^L \equiv u\mod n, L\ge 0\}$. This is always an integer in $[0,p-2]$.

Now, what's with the formula? An integer in $[0,p-1]$ can be interpreted mod $p$, and the possible values are all distinct. Throw in an arbitrary value at zero, and this can be interpreted as a function from $\mathbb{Z}/p$ to itself. It shouldn't be, but it can. Every such function can be written as a polynomial function of degree at most $p-1$, and someone went to the trouble of figuring out what that is in this case. The arbitrary value assigned to zero in this case, by the way, is $0$ if $p=2$ and $-1$ if $p$ is odd.